# Logical Operations in a For Each Row Iteration

Tags: vba, excel

I'm updating a table of capacities which are based on an availability code. Availability codes in specific ranges have the same capacity (with a few exceptions). Each availability code is listed in column "F". The associated capacity is to be listed in column "I".

The goal of the code is to:

- Read the availability code in cell "F" - can be any *nnn* from 300-799
- Determine the range in which it falls - 300-499, 500-599, 600-699, 700-799, with exceptions 762, 763, 764, 765, 768
- Assign a capacity in cell "I" - currently using `Row.Offset`
- Iterate down one row and repeat to the last "F" cell with data

  ```
  Sub Capacity()

  Dim ACNum As Range
  Dim WB As Workbook
  Dim WS As Worksheet

  Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
  Set WS = WB.ActiveWorksheet
  Set ACNum = WS.Range("F:F")

  For Each Row In ACNum.Cells
  Set AC = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
  If (AC = "762" Or AC = "763" Or AC = "764" Or AC = "765" Or AC = "768") Then
      Row.Offset(0, 3).Value = "72"
  ElseIf (AC >= "300" And AC <= "499") Then
      Row.Offset(0, 3).Value = "181"
  ElseIf (AC >= "500" And AC <= "599") Then
      Row.Offset(0, 3).Value = "163"
  ElseIf (AC >= "600" And AC <= "699") Then
      Row.Offset(0, 3).Value = "124"
  ElseIf (AC >= "700" And AC <= "799") And _
      (AC <> "762" Or AC <> "763" Or AC <> "764" Or AC <> "765" Or AC <> "768") Then
      Row.Offset(0, 3).Value = "144"
  End If

  Next Row

  End Sub
  ```

Each time I execute this I receive a generic error, highlighted in yellow, at Line 13, the start of the first `If` statement. If I attempt to use Excel's Evaluate tool, it's options are greyed out and I can't step through the macro.

I'm unable to determine what I'm doing wrong. I haven't worked in Excel VBA for some time so I may be missing a minor detail. This seems so straight-forward.

Comment: You really don't need those many End IF. Just one will do.

Comment: Won't AC always be blank?  You're getting the first non-blank cell in col F (from the bottom up) then offsetting one row down from there... Shouldnt AC just be Row.Value ?   And what @Mrig says - you have too many End If

Comment: @Mrig - if the op code has a problem it's best to correct that in an answer, otherwise there's no indication what the actual problem was...

Comment: @TimWilliams - will take care next time.

Comment: Also, Set AC...... are you trying to assign the range object to AC? AC is also not dimmed. I think you want AC to be a double? and in this case drop the word Set before it. also I don't think you want those double quotes in your if statements. Finally, this would be a LOT quicker if you just did it in one swoop as a formula, you would still use code but take advantage of Excels natural increment abilities and no longer need to loop for example on a new sheet, put some random numbers in A1:A20 then do this in the debug window `range("B1:B20").formula = "=A1*2"`

Comment: @DanDonoghue Yes, I was hoping to use AC as the range to simplify it. I don't know what i was thinking. Clearly over-complicated. Previously, I was using a formula for this task and it worked, but couldn't seem to handle the exceptions when added. There are a lot of good suggestions on the question so I'm going to do some re-working tonight. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**edited**: added a "formula" approach solution

this should do

```
Option Explicit

Sub Capacity()

Dim cell As Range
Dim noNumbers As String
Dim code As Integer

noNumbers = "-762-763-764-765-768-" '<== code exceptions

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Columns("F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<= consider only numbers in "availibility code" column
    With cell
        If InStr(noNumbers, "-" & .value & "-") > 0 Then
            code = 72
        Else
            Select Case .value
                Case 300 To 499
                    code = 181
                Case 500 To 599
                    code = 163
                Case 600 To 699
                    code = 124
                Case 700 To 799
                    code = 144
                Case Else
                    code = -1
            End Select
        End If
        .Offset(0, 3) = code
    End With
Next cell

End Sub
```

as per your explanation I assumed that "availability code" is actually a number so it's much better to declare and use a variable (`code`) of type "integer" to handle it and then use `Select Case` statement to go away with parsing criteria avoiding the repetition of a lot of characters

as Dan Donoghue proposed you may want to use a formula approach. I came up to the following, using the "Median" function as from http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/06/24/between-formula-excel/

```
Sub Capacity2()

With ActiveSheet.Columns("F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<= consider only numbers in "availibility code" column
    .Offset(, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(isnumber(search(""-"" & RC[-3] & ""-"",""-762-763-764-765-768-"")),72," _
                                 & "if(RC[-3]=MEDIAN(RC[-3],300,499),181," _
                                 & "if(RC[-3]=MEDIAN(RC[-3],500,599),163," _
                                 & "if(RC[-3]=MEDIAN(RC[-3],600,699),124," _
                                 & "if(RC[-3]=MEDIAN(RC[-3],700,799),144,-1" _
                                 & ")))))"
End With
```

which, of course, you may also implement directly in excel cells instead of having a VBA macro running

Comment: Thank you! Yes - the "ac"is only numerical. I am re-reading your updated snippet and while I'm out of practice, it's making sense with each re-read. I chose to avoid cases initially because I wasn't sure how to handle the short list of exceptions. I'm going to play with it a bit tonight and rework it similar to this, I believe.

Comment: Whoa. The formula will take some more time to digest. I like the idea of running it in a cell, tho to be honest the ultimate result will be run daily by one person and there are other macro tasks that will have to be done. I'll experiment with both options tho. This is a great help!

Comment: Very nice, nice clean use of Median.

Comment: I'm going to stick with the `Sub` for this application. I tried both options and the `Sub` runs through the various cases faster for my need. But, the formula has taught me some new tricks and I can already see where it's going to be useful. Thanks again, all.