# Logical Operations Loop - Having Complications

Tags: excel, logical-operators, vba

Using wisdom from [one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417532/logical-operations-in-a-for-each-row-iteration), I am writing a statement that:

- For each valid `Flt` check if `AC` is between given numbers
- For each `AC` number range, check if `Bkd` is over a given quantity
- If the conditions are met, change the font/cell color, else skip

Note

- `AC` is column F; `Bkd` is column H; `Flt` is Column G
- `AC` and `Bkd` are matched for each group, as shown in each line of the `If` below

Currently, this generates either error 91, "With block is not set" or a "Type Mismatch" error. I've reviewed my previous questions and taken much of this from fully functioning code but can't seem to make it work. Suggestions?

```
LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
AC = Range("F9:F" & LastRow)
Bkd = Range("H9:H" & LastRow)

With ActiveSheet.Columns("G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    If (AC > "199" And AC < "500" And Bkd > "145") Or _
        (AC > "499" And AC < "600" And Bkd > "130") Or _
         (AC > "599" And AC < "700" And Bkd > "100") Or _
          (AC > "699" And AC < "800" And Bkd > "115") Then
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
        .Interior.Color = vbBlack
    End If
End With
```

This is the other attempted code block referenced in my comment below.

```
Dim AC, Bkd, Flt As Range

LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
AC = Range("F9:F" & LastRow)
Bkd = Range("H9:H" & LastRow)

For Each Flt In ActiveSheet.Columns("G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    With Flt
        If (AC > "199" And AC < "500" And Bkd > "145") Or _
            (AC > "499" And AC < "600" And Bkd > "130") Or _
             (AC > "599" And AC < "700" And Bkd > "100") Or _
              (AC > "699" And AC < "800" And Bkd > "115") Then
            .Font.Color = vbWhite
            .Interior.Color = vbBlack
        End If
    End With
Next Flt
```

Comment: In the answer to your previous question, there is a loop `For each cell in ...`. You need the same approach here.

Comment: I tried an iteration that had `For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Columns("G")...` and the `Next Cell` tag as well, but it also generates a Type Mismatch error. I've made an edit to include the other attempted code block above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of "red flags" in your code.

1. Your declaration of AC and Bkd do not declare them as Ranges. This can cause unexpected behavior.
2. You do not include the Worksheet in your definition of the range. This means, if the active sheet is different than the sheet with the data when you run your macro, you will get unexpected results.
3. You are comparing to, for example, `"199"` instead of `199`. I assume the cell will contain the number 199, and not a text string "199". If it really is a text string, then, in the code below, you should change, for example, `Flt > 199` to `CLng(Flt) > 199`
4. Your code is written like you assume you can evaluate/compare a large Range of values like you can evaluate/compare a single value. This is not the case with VBA - hence you must have a loop to evaluate each individual cell.
5. The use of `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)` will end up affecting the entire worksheet. It should be eliminated.

You haven't provided specific test data with expected results. I achieved these results ...

[image]

... from this code, addressing the issues outlined above ...

```
Sub test()
Dim AC As Range, Bkd As Range, ClrRng As Range
Dim Flt As Range
Dim mySht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set mySht = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <- change this to the sheet you want to use
LastRow = mySht.Range("G" & mySht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set AC = mySht.Range("F9:F" & LastRow)
Set Bkd = mySht.Range("H9:H" & LastRow)
Set ClrRng = mySht.Range("G9:G" & LastRow)

For Each Flt In AC
    If (Flt > 199 And Flt < 500 And Bkd(Flt.Row - 8, 1) > 145) Or _
       (Flt > 499 And Flt < 600 And Bkd(Flt.Row - 8, 1) > 130) Or _
       (Flt > 599 And Flt < 700 And Bkd(Flt.Row - 8, 1) > 100) Or _
       (Flt > 699 And Flt < 800 And Bkd(Flt.Row - 8, 1) > 115) Then

        With ClrRng(Flt.Row - 8, 1)
            .Font.Color = vbWhite
            .Interior.Color = vbBlack
        End With

    End If
Next Flt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you tell in which line your error comes up.

Use this code to define the ranges:

```
Set LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set AC = Range("F9:F" & LastRow)
Set Bkd = Range("H9:H" & LastRow)
```

Comment: I've added "set" for the range definitions. Also, the Type Mismatch comes up for the block starting at `If` and ending at `Then`.

Error 91 will appear on the `Bkd = ` line.

Comment: This is the point where you need the loop. Not looping through ColumnG but looping through AC and Bkd to determine / compare values in each cell and do your formatting.

Comment: My job sent me for training, sorry for the delay. @OldUgly Thank you for pointing out the loop issue. I see where my errors were in looping through the wrong columns and after very slight alteration of your accepted answer, the code is working great!